# Favicon doesn't show up only at Edge at remote server

Tags: http, iis, microsoft-edge, favicon, windows-server

I'm using approach in accordance to codes snippets below.

Add to html:

```
  <link id="shortcutIcon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <link id="icon" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
```

Add minified script after tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(b,c,d,a){a=c+d+b,document.getElementById('shortcutIcon').href=a,document.getElementById('icon').href=a;}(Math.random()*100,(document.querySelector('base')||{}).href,'/assets/images/favicon.ico?v='));
</script>
```

where

- '/assets/images/favicon.ico' related path to .ico
- ?v='Math.random()*100' - to force browser update favicon.ico

as result we have **absolute url** path for favicon.ico.

It works fine for IE, Edge ever at localhost:

But i was faced with **issue** when app was deploy to remote server. The favicon **stops work only for Edge**.

I believe there is some settings issue for Edge.

**Main question** maybe someone have encountered with similar issue.
And has experience with configuration characteristics  necessary for edge to show favicon on remote server. (Windows server, IIS, Edge, Http, security settings)

Comment: Try to clear browser cache and history, then retest your code, whether it works well. Then, try to use F12 developer Network tools to check whether the icon load success? Is there any error? Which version of Microsoft edge are you using?You could also try to resetting the Microsoft Edge browser setting.

Comment: i cleared cache, history (ctr +sft + del) + Ctrl+f5 (hard refresh). There is no errors in console or network. Edge ever didn't try load favicon. Edge version is 41.16299.1004.0. Thanks for help

Comment: Try to directly set the href attribute instead of using Javascript code. Such as using the following code: `<link rel="icon" href="<image url favicon.ico>" type="image/x-icon"> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<image url favicon.ico>" type="image/x-icon"> `

Comment: I did, there was no success. Thus, i believe there are issue with remote settings (security, iis, edge or etc.)

Comment: You could refer to the following steps to resetting the Microsoft Edge browser setting: select the Start  button, then select Settings  > Apps  > Apps & features  > Microsoft Edge > Advanced options. The “Advanced Options” screen will now be displayed. Scroll down until the “Reset” section is visible, as shown in the example below. Next, click on the “Reset” button. If still not working, try to install the latest version of Edge browser.